# map<text, object> Cassandra, is it possible

Tags: dictionary, cassandra

I want to create a table with a map accepting string as key and any object as value (boolean, string, int, timestamp).

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, no, keys and values in a map must be of a known CQL type. There is a [request for "dynamic types"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11466), but nobody has worked on it so far.

Answer (score 2):

Any object isn't possible. You can create user defined types but this type isn't dynamic: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlRefcreateType.html

You can parse your object as json and this json as string. You can insert this string in a text column.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support for dynamic types.

So you got two work arounds.

- Handle it in your application logic.

  - Create `map<text, blob>` or `map<text, text>`
  - Create JSON or ByteBuffer in your application logic. JSON is better as it is language independent, but can consume more storage.
- Create UDT with all the possible types and store it accordingly.

If you have very little variety, then you should choose 2nd option, else 1 should be better. Using 1st option you can store complex objects also.

Hope it helps!